# Alerting the user from a service (Android)

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

So, i have a service working in the background (when the application is closed) which connects to internet every 2 minutes and gets some data from a database, and if something's wrong i want to alert the user with some kind of a beep tone and a message on the screen or even better in the notification bar. Is it possible to do this and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the nicest solution would be to use a `SystemBar` [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Using the [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) you can add a custom sound to your notification using `setSound(Uri sound)`.

Comment: thanks, so is this how you create a notification:
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext) ?

Comment: yeah, and then use the `NotificationManager` to add it to the SystemBar

Answer (score 0):

What you think of is called ´Notification´ in Android. You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on how to create some.